# Is there a way to detect clicks in google sheets and run a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet as shown below.
[image]

The 30 at the bottom is what the title takes to display the points. How do I make it so that when the user clicks the buy button it will deduct the amount of points next to it (ignoring the text) from the 30 at the bottom and add a line below the 30 with it saying the item that was just purchased?

EX: User clicks the "Buy" Button on Item 1. Code takes the numbers only from the previous cell and deducts it from the 30 at the bottom of the sheet then creates a new row under the cell that was 30 and the new line's first cell displays the "Item"
Reference Image:
[image]

If anyone could help me with this that would be great... Thanks!
Update: I have it working now, But how can I make it so that instead of deleting the previous purchases it adds it to an unused line?
Here is the code so far:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const resultA1Notation = "A21"; // Change according to your preferences
  const itemNotation = "A22"; // Change according to your preferences
  const range = e.range;
  const selectedValue = range.getValue();
  if (selectedValue === "Buy") {
    let numberValue = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    const itemValue = range.offset(0, -4).getValue();
    if (numberValue !== "Free") {
      numberValue = numberValue.slice(0, -1); // Remove P
      const resultCell = sheet.getRange(resultA1Notation);
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);
    }
    sheet.getRange(itemNotation).setValue(itemValue + " was purchased!");
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [onSelectChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: I can't in any way I know of apply that to a singular cell though?

Comment: Restrict the rest of the code execution after checking `e.range.getA1Notation`

Comment: Interestingly enough I've been playing with it and I can't get it  to fire at all.

Comment: I shut down the browser session and turned it back  on and now it's working.

Comment: Here's what the event object looks like `{"user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"range":{"columnEnd":1,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{}}`

Comment: `(e.range.rowStart==e.range.rowEnd && e.range.columnStart==e.range.columnEnd)` is always true for single cell selections.

Comment: Are you using any formulas? Do you have any script you are working on? Is the bottom result always in the same cell? Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger, which will fire your function every time a user selects a different cell/range in the spreadsheet. You can do the following:

- Check if the selected value is `Buy`.
- If that's the case, retrieve the number value on its left, and the item name next to it, using [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)).
- Check if the value is `Free`. If that's not the case it is assumed that it is a number and the letter `P`. Remove this last character using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) and update the result cell at the bottom using [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).
- Update the cell below the result number, telling about the item that was purchased, using `setValue` again.

#### Code snippet:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const resultA1Notation = "A11"; // Change according to your preferences
  const itemNotation = "A12"; // Change according to your preferences
  const range = e.range;
  const selectedValue = range.getValue();
  if (selectedValue === "Buy") {
    let numberValue = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    const itemValue = range.offset(0, -2).getValue();
    if (numberValue !== "Free") {
      numberValue = numberValue.slice(0, -1); // Remove P
      const resultCell = sheet.getRange(resultA1Notation);
      resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);
    }
    sheet.getRange(itemNotation).setValue(itemValue + " was purchased!");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- I have assumed that the result at the bottom and the message showing which item was purchased are located in cells `A11` and `A12`. Please change these notations in the code snippet if that's not the case.
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for `onSelectionChange` is currently not documented, but its properties can be known through some little testing (see [Cooper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590090/is-there-a-way-to-detect-clicks-in-google-sheets-and-run-a-function#comment115966395_65590090) showing all the object properties). Specifically, `range` is a property of this object and it is used by the code snippet above.

Comment: @lamblichus I get the following error when I run the code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 5, file "Untitled") How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot call these functions from the script editor because the need a trigger which supplies an event object.  However, you can call them from another function if you supply the event object.

Comment: @Cooper I managed to fix it and now it works. But is there a way to edit the code to instead of replace the information in the cell add a line below it? I don't want the things in the list get deleted if you could help that would be great! :)

Comment: There has also been some confusion with where the cells are, this reference image should help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAwCV.png

Comment: Please post the code as you have modified it into your question.

Comment: @Cooper Done :)

Comment: It looks l ike you could just do this `resultCell.setValue(resultCell.getValue() + '\n' + resultCell.getValue() - numberValue);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226948/discussion-between-eric-and-cooper).

Comment: @Eric Do you mean appending the message `Item X was purchased on the cell below` the last one, instead of editing the cell? If that's the case, you could just replace the last line with `sheet.appendRow([itemValue + " was purchased"])`.